# White Screen on Apache Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm experimenting with .htaccess and trying to rewrite my .php to a alternative url but I keep hitting a white screen.

I can confirm that my apache rewrite is visiting the correct file/filepath and that my php and html is being read once it has been redirected, however my functions for some reason are not working once the url has been rewritten. Alternatively I'm using WordPress permalinks to change page-shop.php to https://mhspeakers.com/shop/ .

My htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 5 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^test$ wp-content/themes/mhspeakers.com/page-shop.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

#Sets Access Control
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'https://mhspeakers.com/homepage'
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'https://mhspeakers.com'
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'origin'

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my shop page without the htaccess rewrite:
https://mhspeakers.com/shop

If I enter the link below which is meant to send me to my page-shop.php, I get a white page however.
https://mhspeakers.com/test

These are the first few lines of my page-shop.php file:

```
<?php 
// Session Start 
session_start(); 

// Connect Handler
include('handler/connect.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MHSpeakers Shop</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Cheshire's leading speaker designer and renovator.">
        <meta name="description" content="Cheshire's leading speaker designer and renovator. We buy, sell and build speakers.">
        <meta property="og:image" src="" alt="Cheshire's leading speaker designer and renovator."/>     
    </head>
 <?php get_header2(); ?>
<body>
    <div class="shop-page">
    <div class="shop-inner center">
    <h1 class="shop-h1">Shop</h1>
    ..................................
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: WSOD (White Screen Of Death) is common if you get a server error (a 500 error) while having display_errors turned off (which you should have in production). Check your web servers error log and see if you see any useful error messages in there. _"I can confirm that my apache rewrite is visiting the correct file/filepath"_ - How did you confirm that? Please add what debugging you've done and the results of it to the question.

Comment: Hi Magnus, thank you for your message. If I replace the above page-shop.php contents with purely HTML or echo "Hi, this is a test", the data will appear. In addition, if I visit dev tools and visit my elements, I can see all of my HTML up until my get_header2() part. Therefore, I believe this is a functions issue.

Comment: Sounds like are working pretty much completely _against_ Wordpress here. If you have a specific page template, then why are you not _assigning_ this to an _actual_ page object with the slug `test`? What are you _actually_ trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hi CBroe, I plan to implement pretty URL's once I've figured out how to rewrite url of a page via htaccess. Pretty URL plugins don't seem to work on my website.